# How to combine GridView and item insertion functionality?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I'm looking for a way to propagate Item Editing in-row GridView UI onto Item Insertion.

I have item insertion form (row) in the footer, but it's visible only when GridView is not empty. So when it is empty, I can't use it, so have a separate form what looks ugly.

I can use external form for insertion all the time but I like that in-row insertion looks visual and handy.

Can I show footer all the time, or emulate similar in-row style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do it:

1-By simulate the Input Fields inside `<EmptyDataTemplate>`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    First Cell
                </td>
                <td>
                    Second Cell
                </td>
                <tb>
                    Third Cell
                </tb>
            </tr>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

2-Is to create Empty `DataSet` and Bind it to the `GirdView`.

I prefer the first way because Binding empty `DataSet` has some problems.

Comment: So EmptyDataTemplate will contain the same table as Footer does, but consolidated (footer is spread among the columns)? And unfortunately there is no way to combine/encapsulate into, say, user control.

Comment: I bind the gridview against strongly typed object model so constructing empty dataset with 20 column looks dirty.

Comment: You can put your user Controls inside the EmptyDataTemplate, actually to save time I look at the HTML of the footer row copy past it to EmptyDataTemplate and modify the HTML controls with my ASP.NET controls. And yes please don't go with binding Empty DataSource it's has issues I'm facing a lot of buggy behavior because of it in one of my projects